# #import <YAJLiOS/YAJL.h> No such file or directory

Tags: yajl

I'm using xcode 4.02, iOSSDK4.3, YAJL 0.2.24.

1. I copied the YAJL.framework folder over to the iPhoneOS4.3sdk frameworks dir and then added the framework to my xcode project (Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries)
2. Build settings - Other linker flags I added -ObjC -load_all to both Debug and Release.
3. Under Framework SearchPaths I added YAJLiOS.framework to both Debug and Release.

I try to compile my project and the header file is not found?

I'm missing something...

whoops.. the Frameworks Search Paths should be set to parent dir of the framework.. for example /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Hi, I'm having a issue with this. The library works fine in my project. But, when I'm trying to use http://osxserver.local (create a bot for analysis) it says: 'YAJLiOS/YAJL.h' file not found. 

Weird. Would you mind to point me which path (parent directory framework)  did you use? . Thanks!